# Conjectured optimal running time for integer factorization

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, prime-factorization

While detecting prime numbers is computationally fast ($O(\log^3 n)$), the fastest known algorithms to split a composite number into its prime factor are very slow (RSA cryptography relies on this assumption). Even the best known algorithms like the number field sieve all run in subexponential time. (Shor's algorithm actually provides a polynomial time algorithm, but on quantum computers.)

I know it is believed that no fast (classical) algorithm exists, but is there a "feeling" as to what could be the optional running time? Often there is a heuristic as to how far you can push the performance long before anybody actually achieves it.

Comment: I was at a talk once where Sarnak said this belief is not well-founded. He compared it to believing the Riemann Hypothesis is false because we haven't found a proof yet.

Comment: As I [understand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity) integer factorization is in FNP, so a polynomial time algorithm would imply FNP=FP, and hence NP=P, so I think it is justified to say that it is wide belief that no such algorithm exists?

Comment: Sorry, this would obviously only hold if the problem was FNP complete. Still, it would have implications to complexity classes that remain unlikely.

Comment: If I am informed right, it is unknown whether prime factorization is NP-complete, so it could be in P, even if $NP\ne P$. What do you mean with "optimal running time" ? With much good luck, or if the factorization is easy, you will get the result very quickly. Please be more precise!

Comment: Indeed, it is conjectured to be in NP-intermediate. What I mean: the fastest known general algorithm is the [general number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) with a running time of $e^{(\sqrt[3]{64/9} + o(1))(\ln n)^{1/3}(\ln \ln n)^{2/3}}$. Since the problem is expected not to be in P, we don't expect it to be pushed to $O(\ln^k n)$, but what is the "feeling" in the research community how far we may get, at least in theory?

Comment: Or to put it another way: when the first RSA challenges were published, it was stated it would take "millennia" to factor them, but they were subsequently factored in a matter of decades, not so much because of advances in hardware, but rather due to advances in the algorithms. I was wondering if some researcher is bold enough to conjecture how much advance may be possible in theory.

Comment: In theory, it may be in P. But of course this is not what you're looking for. I believe what you're looking for is not appropriate for MSE: rampant speculation based on gut feelings.

Comment: A heuristic would do for me... ;)

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I posted after reading the word "feeling" and missed the request for a heuristic. I would however recommend replacing the word "feeling" with a more meaningful alternative.